# CountDownTimer stops inside the Android app when using Google search widget?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm showing the timer in the TextView. I'm adding the code for onPause and onResume method.

Below is the code for countDownTimer. I call this method from the onResume method.

```
public void startCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(total, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                total = millisUntilFinished;
                completedMin = (int) (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)));

                sessionTimerTextView.setText("" + String.format(TIME_FORMAT,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                sessionTimerTextView.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        };

        countDownTimer.start();
    }
```

Below is the code for onResume method

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

        super.onResume();
        startCountDownTimer();
    }
```

Below is the code for onPause method

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

The code works fine when I minimize the app and open any other app but when I use the Google search widget then the timer inside my app stops. What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: How do you know Android is not terminating your app? It generally has the right to do this any time you do not have an `Activity` onscreen, or a `Service` in the background.